# Consider $R=M_{n}(k)$ which $k$ is a field. Properties of $M$ as an $R$-Module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

Consider $R=M_{n}(k)$ which $k$ is a field. We know $M=M_{n \times r}(k)$ is an $R$-Module.

1. When $M$ is Cyclic?
2. When $M$ is Free?
3. When $M$ is Simple?

My ideas:

For the first one, I think if $n=r$, then we can generate $M$ by identity element.

For the second one, If $M$ is Free, then it should be the direct sum of copies of $R$. In this case, $r$ should be equal to $n$. Otherwise, we have missed elements in some columns in our module.

For the third one, $M$ must be equal to $\{0 \}$, otherwise, there are many submodules, pick any matrices with the last zero columns.

But I am feeling that I have missed important things, which I know that I didn't use $k$ as a field. So, it will be great if you help me with that.

Comment: I only gave hints in my answer. Were you able to finish?

Comment: For the first one, I considered $r>n$ and consider $x$ as a generator. So, $Rx=M$. If this is wrong, I should find a contradiction here. I should find an element that can't be generated by x. but I couldn't continue more! maybe there is no contradiction, but if there is no, what is the $x$?

Comment: The third one means this special Ideal you mentioned is exactly $M$. I hope that I understood it right.

Comment: For the second one, If they have the same dimension as k-vector space, So $n^2=rn$. If I am wrong, I have a wrong interpretation of the Direct sum of $R$.

Comment: For the second part, I deduced that $n^2 = rmn$. So, $r | n$ for being $M$ free!

Comment: (1) If $M$ is cyclically generated by $x$ then the map $R\to Rx$ is onto, so $R$ must have dimension  greater than or equal to that of $M$ as a $k$-vector space. So $M$ can't have more columns than $R$ itself. (And conversely, you can show if $r\le n$ then it's cyclic.) (2) Taking $k$-dimensions of $M\cong R^m$ yields $nr=mn^2$ so $r$ is $n$ times how many summands there are in the direct sum. (3) Yes, the only simple module is $k^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) True, $M$ is cyclic if $r=n$. What about if $r<n$? What about if $r>n$?

(2) If $M\cong R^m$ as an $R$-module then they have the same dimension as $k$-vector spaces. What does this require about $r$ with respect to $n$? What about the converse?

(3) True, but you're missing one important case: what if there is only one column, i.e. $r=1$? Can you show this is a simple $R$-module? Indeed, then $M\cong k^n$ as an $R$-module. Moreover,

$$ M\cong \underbrace{(k^n)\oplus\cdots\oplus(k^n)}_r $$

as $R$-modules for general $r$. Do you see how?